vertical scroll not working with pointer input in compose
I need to detect vertical offset of column.
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectVerticalDragGestures { change, _ ->
                            Log.i(TAG, "HomeScreen: position: ${change.position}")
                        }
                    },
            ) {
                repeat(100) {
                    Text(text = "Hello")
                }
            }

if I use detectVerticalDragGestures, the column is no longer be scrollable.
I dont know why verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()) and detectVerticalDragGestures dont work together.

I'm not sure if you want to get the absolute offset or the relative offset of the column's scroll state. You can get a scroll state's current absolute offset by executing as follows:
val scrollstate = rememberScrollState()
scrollstate.value  // --- the current absolute value

In Jetpack Compose, the relative movement of a scrollable object's offset is called a delta. Or, more precisely, a delta is the distance covered by a drag gesture since the last touch contact with the screen (Javeed Ishaq).
ScrollState on a Column or Row does not seem to support detecting deltas out of the box. However, as you have found out, you should not use Modifier.pointerInput to detect a scrollable column's delta value if you want to keep it scrollable. And though you can call scrollstate.animateScrollBy to pass the pointer input's delta value to the scrollable column, it removes the fling effect from the column's scrolling event. In my experience, continuously passing deltas from Modifier.pointerInput to ScrollState also significantly burdens the recomposition of the composables, which lags down the app.
But there is a workaround, which is to use nested scrolling. This article on Medium by Levi Albuquerque explains nested scrolling in Jetpack Compose more thoroughly. But for a general outlook, this is what a functional nested scrolling and scrolling delta detection in Jetpack Compose looks like:
val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
  object : NestedScrollConnection {
    override fun onPreScroll(
      available: Offset,
      source: NestedScrollSource
): Offset {
  val verticalDelta = available.y
  // do whatever you want this delta value.
  
  // if you return "0.0f" or "Offset.Zero", the child elements will continue to scroll.
  // 
  // if you return a non-zero float "available" (the function's parameter),
  // the child elements will not scroll because all of the available deltas
  // have been consumed by the parent (in the below case, by the "Box" element).
  //
  // any float value in between will give you a slower scroll velocity.
  //
  // this is called scroll delta "consumption".
  // read more here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/touch-input/pointer-input/scroll#nested-scrolling
  return Offset.Zero
}

Box (Modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)) {
  // whatever scrollable element you put inside this box will be detected
  // by the aforementioned "nestedScrollConnection", no matter where you put it.
  
  LazyColumn {
    // ... your composables.
  }

  Column (Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
    // ... your composables.
  }

  // this is a non-scrollable object
  Box {
    
    // this lazy column (a scrollable object) lies within a non-scrollable object.
    // yet its deltas will still be detected by the nestedScrollConnection
    LazyColumn {}
  }

  // Also try Row and LazyRow.
}

After connecting the box with nestedScrollConnection, any scrollable child object inside the box will continue to scroll upon user's drag. However, the value of the scrolling deltas are first passed to nestedScrollConnection before the scrolling is actually executed on the child object. Thence, you can read the delta value, store it elsewhere in a variable, and do whatever you want with it.
It's a win-win solution.
